# How to enumerate list of Xsd constraining facets?

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd-validation

I am working on improving user friendliness of Xsd validation error messages, and I need to enumerate all possible constraint facets to be able to further perform search of specific errors within the `ValidationEventArgs`.

Here is the link for the facets list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256149(v=vs.110).aspx

How can I get that list?

Comment: So, you validate XML documents with C#? Then, please show the code that does that - together with a sample XML document and your XML Schema. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy/paste the list from the normative source, the XSD specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#rf-facets